# Network Profile Doesn't List All Accounts

Tags: support, linked-accounts, association, stackexchange.com

I have accounts on Area 51, Cooking, and English, but when I visit [my network profile page](https://stackexchange.com/users/7b7d3917-d33e-4b98-84d1-8072fd6c52ca?tab=accounts) it only shows Area 51 and English (Cooking is missing).

How can I get all my accounts to show as associated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the accounts tab on one of the sites, click the `Clear All Associations` button.  You'll then be able to re-associate everything back together which should fix things up.

Answer (score 0):

Your cooking account isn't associated in both directions; your other SE accounts show up on [Cooking](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/users/5668/sibbaldiopsis?tab=accounts), but Cooking doesn't show up anywhere else (e.g. [MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/160539/sibbaldiopsis?tab=accounts)). You can clear your associations and reassociate to fix it

Comment: I just did that, and it still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: ...or rather, the association seems to work on the "top" and "activity" tabs of my network profile, but not the "accounts" tab where cooking is still missing.

Comment: huh, now it works. I guess there's a time lag.