# How does Stack Exchange know that two accounts belong to the same person?

Tags: support, user-accounts, moderation, sock-puppets

A related question ([How do stackexchange sites know that two usernames correspond to the same person?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2248/how-do-stackexchange-sites-know-that-two-usernames-correspond-to-the-same-person)) says it's because the email addresses are the same.

But in my case, the accounts were identified despite differing (but very similar) email addresses.

How could Stack Exchange know that the two accounts belong to the same person?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What should one do when they have been accused wrongly of using sockpuppets, and can the deleted accounts be recovered?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357752/what-should-one-do-when-they-have-been-accused-wrongly-of-using-sockpuppets-and)

Comment: @SonictheSaveUkraine-hog while that suggested duplicate is somewhat related, it doesn't appear to actually answer this question.

Comment: Sometimes they know: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251268/282094 ***and***  sometimes they don't:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/163716/282094 
https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86041/282094  https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/109054/282094  
https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87731/282094

Comment: I'd leave this open as a support request, but actually telling you what broke is probably a security issue; and not going to be detailed.

Comment: @Rob I'm voting to close as unclear. There are currently 2 perfectly fine answers, which could both answer this question, but answer totally different questions at the same time. So more focus is needed here.

Comment: @Luuklag, [Agreed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zQsM.png), because they're not coming back to accept an answer.

Answer (score 32):

Moderators do not disclose the methods and tools used for identifying sock puppet accounts.

Comment: So basically... Magic.

Comment: The exact ritual incantations used with the moderators' scrying orbs to identify such accounts are among our most closely guarded secrets, as are the required sacrifices and the appropriate amounts of incense to burn.

Answer (score 6):

The linked question is about ascertaining identity for the purpose of merging accounts as opposed to detecting sockpuppet abuse.
The criteria for merging are stricter for the following reasons:

- If accounts belonging to different people were merged, this would be a privacy issue since one of them may now have access to private information of the other. Also, merging is difficult to undo.
- A false positive for a sockpuppet abuse “only” results in things like suspensions and vote invalidations, which can be easily undone. Also, it’s often impossible to distinguish meatpuppet¹ and sockpuppet abuse, but since both are not allowed and lead to the same consequences, the distinction is not very relevant. By contrast, merging meatpuppets would be problematic.

Also, the linked Q&A is more than ten years old and moderators cannot merge accounts anymore.

---

¹ A meatpuppet is like a sockpuppet, only that the second account actually belongs to another person whom the puppeteer tells to vote up their posts, etc.